# How to limit a like counter based on the cookie of the user instead of logged in user?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

I use Intercooler.js for a small like counter I have. It is basically just a `IntegerField` field in a Django model named `value` and then all the logic gets handled in the view like this:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Counter


def index(request, template_name="counter.html"):
    if request.GET.get('ic-request'):
        counter, created = Counter.objects.get_or_create(pk=1)
        counter.value += 1
        counter.save()
    else:
        counter, created = Counter.objects.get_or_create(pk=1)
        print(counter.value)
    context = dict(
        value=counter.value,
    )
    return render(request, template_name, context=context)
```

In the template you write it like HTML, without a single line of JavaScript:

```html
<button ic-get-from="{% url 'index' %}" ic-target="#wrapper" ic-select-from-response="#wrapper" class="btn btn-success btn-sm my-2 mr-1" ><i class="fe-icon-heart"></i>&nbsp;<div id="wrapper">Like {{ value }}</div></button>
```

So that's pretty cool. However right now you can just hit the like button forever. Is there some way to add a bit of (JavaScript) to limit the likes to one based on the cookie of the user rather than the person logged in? But still using Intercooler.js

Answer (score 0):

You can set something on `request.session` which will tell you if it was liked or not; otherwise, you can use cookies and expire them whenever you want:

```
def index(request, template_name="counter.html"):
    already_liked = request.session.get('already_liked')
    counter = Counter.objects.filter(pk=1).first() # i don't want to add try/except now
    if not already_liked:
        if request.GET.get('ic-request'):
            if counter:
                counter.value += 1
                counter.save()
                request.session['already_liked'] = True
            else:
                counter, created = Counter.objects.get_or_create(pk=1)
                counter.value += 1
                counter.save()
                request.session['already_liked'] = True
         else:
             counter, created = Counter.objects.get_or_create(pk=1)
             request.session['already_liked'] = True # duplicating this because I don't have a full overview of your project
    if counter:
        value = counter.value # not sure what are the whole expectations of this flow
    else:
        value = 0 # so we return something on context
    context = dict(
        value=counter.value,
    )
    return render(request, template_name, context=context)
```